# How to ignore telnetlib errors and continue For loop in python

Tags: python, ip-address, telnet, telnetlib

I want to use telnetlib with python to telnet range of IPs so I used this code

```
import ipaddress
import telnetlib
import time

def looping_ip() :
    for j in range(1, 50, 1):
        ip = "192.168.1.%d" % (j)
        connection = telnetlib.Telnet()
        connection.open(ip)
        connection.read_until("Password:")
        connection.write("admin"+"\n")
        connection.read_eager()
        return True
```

The problem is when I execute that code if there's an IP isn't available it show this error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    connection.open(ip)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I want to ignore any error and continue the loop till I stopped it.
please your answer should be with python not any language else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ipaddress
import telnetlib
import time

def looping_ip() :
    for j in range(1, 50, 1):
        ip = "192.168.1.%d" % (j)
        try:
            connection = telnetlib.Telnet()
            connection.open(ip)
            connection.read_until("Password:")
            connection.write("admin"+"\n")
            connection.read_eager()
            return True
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: nothing happened only code show that only
===================== RESTART: /root/Desktop/testing.py =====================
>>>

Comment: I'm not sure what that output means in your case. The use of the `try` and `except` block was only meant to bypass any errors that would arise a result of trying to open a connection with an invalid ip.

Comment: output means the code isn't correct, code run and end immediately.

Comment: The looping_ip() function will return `None` if all the ip addresses in that range produce an error. Consider how that return value of `None` affects your surrounding code.

Comment: I edited somethings and it works fine,, thank you Onel :)